# localhost prepended to web address

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, url, mobile

In jquery, I am reading web addresses from xml to append to a jquery mobile list-view using:

```
<script>
            var coupons = [];
            var names = [];
            var li = "<li><a href='#' rel='external'></a></li>"; 
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "data/xml/markers.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: parseXml
            });
            function parseXml(xml) {
                var counter = 1;                 
                 $(xml).find("marker").each(function () {
                    name = $(this).find("name").text();
                    web = $(this).find("web").text();
                    names[counter] = name;
                    //web += "/coupons/"
                    //web += name.toString(); 
                    coupons[counter] = web;
                    $("#couponlinks").append(li);
                    alert(couponlinks[counter]);
                    counter++;

                 });
                    $("#datalist li a").each(function (index) {
                    this.text = names[index];
                    alert(coupons[index]);
                    this.href = coupons[index]; // this appends the web address plus the      localhost
                });

            }            
        </script>
```

The actual web address gets prepended with the localhost and does not point to the actual address.
i.e. wwww.thewebsite.com comes out with the localhost prepended to the web variable.

I do not understand this behavior. Thanks for any help.

*Also, when I append 'li' it appears as a regular link and not a fancier $.mobile listview item.

*Stackoverflow will not allow the localhost term so I subsituted lclhost. TY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a relative URL.
Strings like `www.something.com/a` are actually a relative URL, pointing to a folder named `www.something.com`.

You need to use an absolute URL, starting with the protocol (`http://`)